# SmartGit removes(from rep.panel) my github's cloned repos

Tags: github, smartgit

Still in local repos folder they appear to be.

What I have: `Ubuntu` 18.04, attached `bitbacket` repos(they appear every run of `SmartGit`)

What I did: Added `gpg` key to `SmartGit`, successfully attached log/pass of `GitHub` to `SmartGit`. Same mail on `SmartGit` and `GitHub`.

Everything works just fine, until I close app and reboot `Linux`. Then they're gone.
I don't know what to do to solve this problem, I've tried to google it, but nothing any helpful.

Comment: Try to readd the repository to SmartGit's known repositories list using **Repository|Add or Create**, then exit SmartGit using **Repository|Exit** and restart. Is the repository still present now?

Comment: @mstrap indeed. I did it and test it for 2 days. It works, all repos appear and functional. It's a bug? Thanks for help! You can probably cp it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SmartGit is somewhat sensitive to ungraceful shutdowns which typically occur when rebooting your machine without having exited SmartGit before. To solve this, readd the repository to SmartGit's known repositories list using **Repository|Add or Create**, then exit SmartGit using **Repository|Exit** and restart.